# dav_svn write access

Tags: ldap, svn

Good day!

I am configuring dav_svn and apache with ldap auth.

What I want to do:

- allow anonymous READ access to repo
- allow write access to authenticated users

Here comes my config:

```
    # Uncomment this to enable the repository
    DAV svn

    SVNPath /home/svn/ldap-test-repo
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "LDAP-REPO Repository"

    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=svn,ou=applications,dc=company,dc=net"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "pass"
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.company.net:389/ou=Users,dc=company,dc=net?uid?sub?(objectClass=person)

    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            Allow from all
    </Limit>

    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            Require ldap-group cn=group,ou=services,dc=company,dc=net
    </LimitExcept>
```

But when I do a test this config doesn't work... I can do checkout without auth and commit without auth...

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all :)

It was my fault. svn caches my auth data at ~/.subversion dir. When I removed it server asks me a login information.

Comment: Many svn commands have parameter "--no-auth-cache" to avoid confusion